# How can there be an electric field normal to the surface in a surface plasmon in a metal

Tags: solid-state-physics, plasma-physics, plasmon

Ashcroft and Mermin's Solid State Physics, chapter one, has an exercise about surface plasmons. They give the electric field normal to the surface of the metal as $E_z=Be^{iqx}e^{-Kz}$ How can this be? Wouldn't this imply a current going out of the metal? Shouldn't a negative charge accumulate at the boundary, cancelling the field?

Comment: Why would it imply a current?

Comment: Well, this is *inside* the metal, so isn't the current equal to the conductivity times the electric field?

Comment: I see. I thought you were talking about the field outside.

Answer (score 0):

It is a characteristic of conductors at electrostatic equilibrium is that the electric field upon the surface of the conductor is directed entirely perpendicular to the surface.

Comment: Oh, yeah... But the problem statement has components both normal and parallel to the surface.

Comment: And even in the interior.

Comment: These are fields *inside* the metal, contrary to the usual treatment of conductors. It is a mystery to me.

Comment: In your case, you should look at the boundary condition of Maxwell's equation in the medium from respective portions in Griffith's electrodynamic book.